# Resize text with bounding box and character styles - Photoshop C6/CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, resize, character-styles, creative-cloud

Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EHJ1zvCed0) with the bug.

Resizing text with the bounding box can't be restored by character styles. No matter what you do, you have to create a new point/paragraph text and start all over again and never, ever resize it with the bounding box, which is really annoying.

Any idea how to reset the font-size if you used a bounding box to resize the text?

Thanks & enjoy,

Comment: This is not a bug, it's expected behavior. You are setting a size than scaling it. Are you expecting Photoshop to alter Character Styles based on transformations? That would spawn a whole slew of bug reports on that. Transforming anything other than pixels doesn't alter the original, for example Smart objects.

Comment: The profanity wasn't all that necessary in that video.

Comment: Bug or not is messing up a valid workflow. There is no way to reset transformation. Should I use smart objects for all my texts? That won't work either. And no, the profanity wasn't necessary at all, sorry for that.